# Regex `[quote]`

Tags: regex

I have a string as follows:

```
'[quote]Originally Posted by <strong>first last</strong><br/>zzzzzzzzz[/quote]adaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
```

I would like to get the first occurence of `[quote]` and the last occurence of `[/quote]` and remove everything in between.

Comment: Which language? With PHP and preg_replace, you could do something like `preg_replace('#\[quote\]([^\]]+)\[/quote\]#U', '', $str);`

Comment: i am using ColdFusion's REReplace. Gumbo's suggestion worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any further knowledge of your regular expression implementation, try the following regular expression and replace the match string by an empty string:

```
\[quote].*\[/quote]
```

Since the `*` quantifier is greedy, it will allow as much repetitions of characters matched by `.` as possible.

Comment: Are the `]` characters not escaped because the opening `[` characters are escaped and so won't be interpreted as character classes anyway?

Comment: Don't use .*  ... Much better to check for actual characters or use a negation.

Comment: As you said yourself, * quantifier is greedy. If you had the string `[quote]Hello[/quote] I am a string [quote]World[/quote]`, it would delete everything from the first [quote] to the **last** [/quote]. May not be what you want!

Comment: @Cfreak: Do you mean a look-ahead assertion? What if the regular expression implementation does not support look-ahead assertions?

Comment: @Vincent Savard: Yes, the `[quote]` before `Hello` is the first occurrence of `[quote]` and the `[/quote]` after `World` is the last occurrence of `[/quote]`. So what’s wrong?

Comment: oh wow, thanks Gumbo. That works perfect. I am using ColdFusion.

Comment: @FALCONSEYE: Are you sure you don’t want the shortest match instead of the longest match?

Comment: @Gumbo : For example, you don't necessarily want to do this for bbCode. There's nothing wrong (because we don't know more), but it may be wrong.

Comment: @Vincent Savard: Most bbCode variants are irregular.

Comment: ok??? I don't see what this has to do with anything. I'm just precising your answer, in case this is not what OP wants.

Comment: @Vincent Savard: Oh, I thought you were rather criticizing my answer. Well then, no offense!